# Uneven coloring basil leaves

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, basil

I have seen this from time to time   Where the color of the leaves is uneven. This year I purchased the plants from two sources. One batch is nice even color and the others somewhat splotchy. Just trying to understand what this is indicating since it doesn’t seem optimal.

[image]